# What is the difference between the positional encoding techniques of the Transformer and GPT?

Tags: comparison, transformer, gpt, positional-encoding

I know the original Transformer and the GPT (1-3) use two slightly different **positional encoding** techniques.

More specifically, in GPT they say positional encoding is *learned*. What does that mean? OpenAI's papers don't go into detail very much.

How do they really differ, mathematically speaking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of introduction of positional encoding  is to insert a notion of location of a given token in the sequence. Without it, due to the permutation equivariance (symmetry under the token permutation) there will be no notion of relative order inside a sequence.

Given a token at $\text{pos}$-th position we would like to make the model understand, that this token is at particular position. See pretty nice blog here - https://kazemnejad.com/blog/transformer_architecture_positional_encoding/.

**Fixed encoding**

In the [original Transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) one uses a fixed map from the token position $i$ to the embedding vector added to the original embedding:
$$
\begin{aligned}
PE(\text{pos}, 2i) &= \sin(\text{pos} / 10000^{2i / d_{\text{model}}}) \\
PE(\text{pos}, 2i + 1) &= \cos(\text{pos} / 10000^{2i / d_{\text{model}}})
\end{aligned}
$$

Here $\text{pos}$ is an index of the token in sequence, and $2i, 2i+1$ correspond to the dimension inside the embedding.

**Learned encoding**

Another strategy is to make map for $\text{pos}$ to the embedding vector of dimension $d_{\text{model}}$ *learnable*. One initializes somehow for each position in the sequence vector of positional embedding for each position from $0$ to $\text{max_length}$ and during the training these vectors are updated by gradient descent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, the difference is the following: original Transformers use a fixed type of encoding, based on sine/cosine functions.

On the other hand, GPT produces two embedding vectors: one of the input tokens, as usual in language models, and another for token positions themselves.